# Why saving Image object is not the same for thumbnail() and resize()?

Tags: python-3.x, save, python-imaging-library, image-resizing

```
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance, ImageFilter

image = "Ash and Pikachu.png"
image = Image.open(image)
images = image.thumbnail((400, 320))   # thumbnail() works by changing the var name
# image = image.thumbnail((400, 320))  # gives error by keeping same var name
image.save("NewImage.png")
```

The above code will convert the image to thumbnail as expected. But by replacing `thumbnail()` with `resize()`, it just copies and saves the source image with new name.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance, ImageFilter

image = "Ash and Pikachu.png"
image = Image.open(image)
# images = image.thumbnail((400, 320))  # doesn't throw errors but doesn't resize the image
image = image.resize((400, 320))        # resize() works by keeping same var name
image.save("NewImage.png")
```

I'm not using both at the same time, but just wanted to point out where I'm facing issues. Anyhow, can I use the same code to save images in both `thumbnail()` and `resize()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's see the documentation on [`Image.thumbnail`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html?highlight=thumbnail#PIL.Image.Image.thumbnail):

> Note that this function modifies the `Image` object in place.

And, the documentation on [`Image.resize`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html?highlight=resize#PIL.Image.Image.resize) states:

> Returns a resized copy of this image.

So, the correct usage of both methods including saving looks like this:

```py
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open('path/to/your/image.png')
image.thumbnail((200, 200))
image.save('thumbnail.png')

image = Image.open('path/to/your/image.png')
image = image.resize((200, 200))
image.save('resize.png')
```

Both save a `(200, 200)` version of the input image. Notice: There's no reassignment of `image` in the first case, but in the second. That's in line with your codes. Inspect `images` in your first case, it's no proper `Image` object (it's `None` actually), but saving `image` still works, because `Image.thumbnail` worked in place. In your second case, you explicitly reassign `image`, which is correct here.

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:    Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:      3.8.5
Pillow:      8.0.1
----------------------------------------
```